# How to merge 2 arrays - nest one array into another

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array:

```
$form['info'] = array(...);
$form['container'] = array(...);
```

and I have another array:

```
$container['item_1'] = array(...);
$container['item_2'] = array(...);
```

I would like to get a structure like this:

```
$form['info']
$form['container']['...']
$form['container']['item_1']
$form['container']['item_2']
```

How could I merge $form and $container array to achieve this? I need to nest/add all items from $container array into $form['container'] variable. `array_merge()` does not seems to work this way.

Comment: What code (exactly) are you using in attempt to merge? Could you supply source?

Comment: How have you used `array_merge()`?

Comment: The source is too complicated so I made this simple example.

Comment: @dr_debug array_merge($form, $container);

Comment: $form['container']['item_1'] it will give you merged array with container and item1 values. right?

Comment: $form['container']['item_1'] should return the same as $container['item_1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `array_merge()` is not working? Your task is to merge `$form['container']` with `$container` as I understand. `array_merge()` can handle this.

```
$form['container'] = array_merge($form['container'], $container);
```

Comment: Yes, this is a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should handle it:

```
foreach($container as $key => $value){
    $form['container'][$key] = $value;
}
```

1. Iterate your `$container`and get its key-vaule-pairs
2. Append them to your `$form`

Comment: Thanks, this works. I think there is no native php function for this kind of merging.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php
$form["info"] = array('info');
$form["container"] = array('container');
$container['item_1'] = array('1');
$container['item_2'] = array('2');

foreach($container as $k=>$f)
{
    $form['container'][$k] = $f;
}
print_r($form);
?>
```